# SET_ROWID_THRESHOLD - ORA-29971

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I'm using oracle v19.0. I tried using DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION instead of trigger. It is working correctly and inserted data into a new table.
But working with max 100 rowid: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2287997_1.html

Tried increase this value with following command:
`SQL> exec dbms_change_notification.SET_ROWID_THRESHOLD('SCH.TABLE', 1000);`
I got this exception:

```
ORA-29971: Specified table name not found or does not have any registrations
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION", line 217
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

This error happens only with partitioned tables.
Can you give any details about this? Why work with the only non-partitioned table?
Thank you!

Comment: you need grant on system tables. do you gave dba priv. on db?

Comment: Yes, user has DBA privileges.

Comment: can you try this ? DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.SET_ROWID_THRESHOLD

Comment: Yes, but DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION is just synonym for DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION:
select * from dba_synonyms where synonym_name = 'DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION';
So, same error happened.

Comment: My guess is that each partition has to be registered separately, because if a row moves between partitions, its ROWID changes, which counts as a change to be monitored. See if the table partitions show up in the DBA_CQ_NOTIFICATION_QUERIES view, which I think is what that procedure is looking at.

Comment: Cannot define exact partition in registration block. If I added PARTITION part in select then I got: ORA-29976: Unsupported query for registration in guaranteed mode